# Unable to close the Git Repository Configuration window on VisualStudio for Mac after switching to a branch

Tags: git, macos, version-control, visual-studio-mac

I'm using git project on VisualStudio for Mac. I'm trying to switch branch from master to a dev branch by using the menu
**Version Control** > **Manage Branches and Remotes**. 
Branch switched successfully but I am unable to close the Git Repository Configuration window. Close button or window cross nothing works. I can move the window that means no window gets hang or stuck on some process. Please check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NGnB.png). And I'm new on VisualStudio for Mac. Do I miss something? I checked no confirmation popup holds this. Does anyone face similar things?
FYI, I'm using the VisualStudio for Mac Community version 8.3.8 (build 8)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, the only way I can exit the program is by force quitting (v. 8.5.3)

Comment: Same here. I think I accidently minimized some dialog that was displayed, after which the "Git Repository Configuration" dialog is completely frozen. Doesn't matter where I click, i just can't seem to close the dialog anymore. Tried restarting VS for Mac, but as soon as I want to do something with 'branches' i'm stuck again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the VS for Mac preference folder `~/Library/Preferences/VisualStudio/8.0/` to reset the application to installation defaults.